# Mailchimp Subscribe with Profile:Edit / Cartthrob

Tags: members, cartthrob, email, extension

I'm having problems getting Mailchimp Subscribe working when used in conjunction with Profile:Edit registrations or Cartthrob Checkout. Does anyone know if there are known conflicts with these Extensions/Modules.

Running EE v2.5.2
Cartthrob 2.2.2
Profile:Edit 1.0.7
Mailchimp Subscribe 2.1.0

The problem is that I've set a custom member field (member_subscribe). In mailchimp subscribe settings this is set as the trigger field and the trigger is 'Yes'. Once member has registered the trigger field is shown as Yes but when I login to Mailchimp there are no subscriptions registering under lists.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide a better description of what 'having problems' means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of [MailChimp Subscribe](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sl-mailchimp-subscribe) on Devot-ee hasn't been updated in nearly 18 months, and the developer (Steven Lewis) is no longer actively developing it himself.

**However**, there are [a number of forks on Github](https://github.com/experience/mailchimp_subscribe.ee_addon/network) that add enhancements, including (I think) CT compatibility and Safecracker Registration support too.

Some of these have been merged into the original, so grab the [version from GitHub](https://github.com/experience/mailchimp_subscribe.ee_addon/) rather than Devot-ee for starters, as they probably fix a number of issues/incompatibilities with recent EE versions.

Other than that as @Tyssen says you really need to provide more information about the specific issues you're having.

As an alternative approach, have a look at the (free) [CT Mailing list addon](https://github.com/CartThrob/addon-mailing_list) instead. It's made by BNI (who make CT & Profile:Edit) and it allows you to hook directly into CT's checkout process. You could probably also pretty easily extend/reuse the same code to tie into one of [Profile: Edit's hooks](http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/profile-edit/#extension-hooks)

Comment: Tyssen. By having problems I mean that I've set a custom member field (member_subscribe). In mailchimp subscribe settings this is set as the trigger field and the trigger is 'Yes'. Once member has registered the trigger field is shown as Yes but when I login to Mailchimp there are no subscriptions registering under lists. Problem. Tom I'll try some of the forks on git or the CT Mailing list addon (which I wasn't aware of) thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi Micky, probably best to add his info about your specific issue as an edit to your question as it more likely to get seen there than as a comment on my answer.

Comment: You can also use a proper API that is actively developed. Checkout my add-on Postmaster. It's not free, but it's a premium product that is actively supported and used by many. https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster

Answer (score 1):

Any solution for EE 2.8 out there?
The suprisehighway hack is causing errors:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Javascript::generate_json() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laatmaarzien/e2services/expressionengine/third_party/mailchimp_subscribe/ext.mailchimp_subscribe.php on line 274

Comment: Discovered the same problem with the native SL Mailchimp Subscribe version. I might go with another solution as it hasn't been updated in 3 years.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, and should be a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issues. We hacked our way to a solution.

https://github.com/surprisehighway/MailChimp-Subscribe-Profile-Edit